# Avoid a loop in index page

Tags: struts2

I have this index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Simple Iterator</h2>
<ol>
<s:iterator value="comboMeals">
  <li><s:property /></li>
</s:iterator>
</ol>

<h2>Iterator with IteratorStatus</h2>
<table>
<s:iterator value="comboMeals" status="comboMealsStatus">
  <tr>
    <s:if test="#comboMealsStatus.even == true">
      <td style="background: #CCCCCC"><s:property/></td>
    </s:if>
    <s:elseif test="#comboMealsStatus.first == true">
      <td><s:property/> (This is first value) </td>
    </s:elseif>
    <s:else>
      <td><s:property/></td>
    </s:else>
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my Java Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class IteratorKFCAction extends ActionSupport{

    private List<String> comboMeals;

    public List<String> getComboMeals() {
        return comboMeals;
    }

    public void setComboMeals(List<String> comboMeals) {
        this.comboMeals = comboMeals;
    }

    public String execute() {

        comboMeals = new ArrayList<String>();
        comboMeals.add("Snack Plate");
        comboMeals.add("Dinner Plate");
        comboMeals.add("Colonel Chicken Rice Combo");
        comboMeals.add("Colonel Burger");
        comboMeals.add("O.R. Fillet Burger");
        comboMeals.add("Zinger Burger");

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

My idea was call directly the action that fill the index page, so i put this line inside head tags of index.jsp

```
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL='start.do'">
```

But with with this fix, i get that the page enter in a "refresh loop". Is there any way to call directly from the code the action, in this way I don't have to set it manually via URL in the browser.

I've tried also a second solution adding to the body of index.jsp this code:

```
 <s:action name="iteratorKFCAction" executeResult="true" />
```

where iteratorKFCAction is the action specified in struts.xml that recall the IteratorKFCAction. In this case the action loop.

Comment: Redirect away from the index.jsp. index.jsp -> action -> some.jsp.

Comment: No, I simply want to show directly the action in index.jsp. Is it possible?

Comment: Even if something is possible, it doesn't mean it's a good idea. <s:action /> tag is a legacy tag you should never use on new development, and the meta refresh trick is another bad practice from the past... can't you simple use an action as welcome page, or a jsp redirecting to an action ?

Answer (score 2):

The main purpose of Struts2 (and all other MVC frameworks) is to route the URL to an Action (the Controller) that prepare data (in your case `comboMeals`) and determine a result (in your case always `SUCCESS`) that is mapped to a template (the View), in your case `index.jsp`

In your `struts.xml` you should have something like

```
<action name="start.do" class="com.xxx.IteratorKFCAction">
    <result name="SUCCESS">/WEB-INF/.../index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: `start.do` as an action name? Usually the part after `.` is an action extension.